# Input and Output from a File in C

Tags: c, file-io, output

This homework assignment is:

- Implement a program that mimics the ECE 173 class roster. The roster has a maximum of 50 students.
- Each student has a last name, first name, student ID, possible scores for programming assignments (1–5), and possible scores for tests (1 and 2). Use structures and functions to develop the program.
- The program should take all input (e.g., roster size, number of programming assignments, number of test, and the information for each of the student) from a file. When all of the information is entered, the user should be able to display the entered information and also have the screen output written to a file.
- Note: Your submission must include five different input files that you had used to test your program.

I have done the first part relating to the ECE 173 class roster. However I'm really struggling with the input/output part of this assignment. This is what I have right now; it builds successfully but when running the program, it stops.

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct test{double testgrade;
};
struct hw{double hwgrade;
};
struct student{
char first[30];
char last[30];
int stuID;
struct hw hwamount[5];
struct test testamount[2];
};

int main() {

int rostersize;
int testnumber;
int hwnumber;

FILE *fp;
FILE * fop;
fp = stdin;
fop = stdout;

fp = fopen("eceroster_in.txt", "r");
fop = fopen("eceroster_out.txt", "w");

//fprintf(fp, "How many students are there?\n");
fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &rostersize);
    while (rostersize >50){
        //printf("Roster cannot exceed 50 students!\n");
        fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &rostersize);
}
    struct student roster[50];

//fprintf(fp, "How many tests are there?\n");
fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &testnumber);
    while (testnumber >2){
        //printf("Cannot exceed 2 tests!\n");
        fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &testnumber);
}
//fprintf(fp,"How many assignments are there?\n");
fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &hwnumber);
    while (hwnumber >5){
    //fprintf (fp, "Cannot exceed 5 assignments!\n");
    fscanf_s(fp,"%d", &hwnumber);
}
for (int i = 0; i < rostersize; i++){

//fprintf(fp, "Enter student's last name:\n");
fscanf_s(fp, "%s", &(roster[i].last));

//fprintf(fp, "Enter student's first name:\n");
fscanf_s(fp, "%s", &(roster[i].first));

//fprintf(fp, "Enter the student's ID:\n");
fscanf_s(fp, "%i", &(roster[i].stuID));

for (int j = 0; j < testnumber; j++){

//fprintf(fp, "Enter the student grade for test %d\n", j+1);
fscanf_s(fp, "%lf", &(roster[i].testamount[j].testgrade));
}

for (int k = 0; k < hwnumber; k++){

//fprintf(fp, "Enter the student grade for assignment %d\n", k+1);
fscanf_s(fp, "%lf", &(roster[i].hwamount[k].hwgrade));
    }
}
//fprintf(fp, "How many times would you like your roster to print?\n");
    int rosterAmount;
    fscanf_s(fp, "%d", &rosterAmount);

for (int j = 0; j < rosterAmount; j++){
 for (int k = 0; k < rostersize; k++){

    fprintf(fop, "Name: %s %s \n", &(roster[k].first, roster[k].last));
    fprintf(fop, "Student ID: %d\n", &(roster[k].stuID));

for (int mm = 0; mm < testnumber; mm++){
    fprintf(fop, "Test %d: %.1f\n", &
(mm+1,roster[k].testamount[mm].testgrade));
        }

for (int m = 0; m < hwnumber; m++){
    fprintf(fop, "Assignment %d: %.1f\n", &   (m+1,roster[k].hwamount[m].hwgrade));
        }

  fprintf(fop, "_______________________________\n");
    }
}
fclose (fp);
fclose (fop);

return 0;
}
```

It builds successfully, but it has an error "Debug Assertion Failed! when trying to debug

Comment: You can't print and scan to the same file at the same time.

Comment: Tip: posting "deadlines" in StackOverflow is always a bad idea.  Two whole days to debug your homework is plenty of time.

Comment: What were you trying to do with this line: `FILE * fopen(char * eceroster, char * r);`? Open the file `"eceroster"` with mode `"r"`? If so, that won't do that.

Comment: `fp` is a null pointer, and you never set it to anything else. You never call `fopen`. (You do uselessly *declare* `fopen`. Don't do that; you already declared it by including `<stdio.h>`.)

Comment: You are using `fp` for two _different_ streams: one for _input_ and one for _output_. That doesn't work [even if it doesn't segfault, like what you're getting now ;-)]. You need _two_: (e.g. `fpi` for input and `fpo` for output). Then, change all `fprintf` to use `fpo` and all `fscanf_s` to use `fpi`. Probably, you'll also want `fpi = stdin;` and `fpo = stdout;`

Comment: Please learn to indent your code; it makes it hard to read if you don't.

Comment: BTW `%s` of [fscanf_s](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ybhk9kc.aspx) need buffer size.

Comment: Could you give the full error information? "Debug Assertion Failed!" sounds like just its title.

Answer (score 1):

I am missing points to post a comment, so using answer. You have to:

> The program should take all input (e.g., roster size, number of
>   programming assignments, number of test, and the information for each
>   of the student) from a file.

Which means: there is no point of asking on a command line for number of students, tests. You start with creating some easy to parse text data files containing info about the students, assert that num_of_students < 51, names of students or at least their IDs are unique, etc. 
Apart from good input files you should also create few screwed ones. So you can show how your program handles bad inputs.

And then think about few essential use cases for that data:

1. a student wants to know his courses / grades
2. prof Smith needs to know all the students participating in his
   course
3. summaries: how many: students, courses, students per course

Nobody is going to check this program is going to put i.e. 51 names, IDs, plus say 100 grades by hand on the command line, and as it is stated in the quoted part of the assignment, it is neither needed nor expected.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks, I can put my new powers to a good use. While you assignment is in C, you may use i.e. Python for a prototyping/creating data files. If you know that datafiile_1.tsv van be parsed by your Python script easily, you will save a lot of time trying to duplicate the functionality in C. Otherwise instead of learning C you will waste time to find some extra space, missing coma, etc. in the throwaway data files. Best